# An ammend recipe program solution for python version 3

Tags: python

I wonder if anybody has a solution to this.
I keep getting errors and my program not working accordingly for the recipe task for OCR GCSE Computing. I have manage to create the add recipe in an external text file and also search for an existing recipe.

What I am having problems with is re -calculating the new quantities (all numeric data) for different number of people for the recipe. I am using Python version 3.

my amend program sections is as below. (I defaulted all recipe for 1 person) so it is easier to recalculate new quantity.

My code is as below.**

I appreciate your help in advance.

```
import os

def modify():
    #create a boolean variable to use as a flag
    found = False

    #Get the search value and the new recipe information.
    search = input ("Enter a recipe name to search for: ")
    new_number_of_people =input("Enter the new number of people to serve (default is 1):")


    #open the original recipeList.txt file.
    recipeList_file=open("recipeList.txt", "r")

    #open the temporary file.
    temp_file = open("temp.txt", "w")

    #Read the first record's recipe name field
    recipe = recipeList_file.readline()


    #Read the rest of the file.
    while recipe != "":
         #Read the recipe item,quantity, units and number of people.
        ingredient1 = str(recipeList_file.readline())
        quantity1 =float(recipeList_file.readline())
        units1 = str (recipeList_file.readline())
        ingredient2 = str(recipeList_file.readline())
        quantity2 =float(recipeList_file.readline())
        units2 = str (recipeList_file.readline())        
        ingredient3 = str(recipeList_file.readline())
        quantity3 =float(recipeList_file.readline())
        units3 = str (recipeList_file.readline())        
        number_of_people = float(recipeList_file.readline())

        recipe = recipe.rstrip("\n")


         #write a new record with the temp file
        if recipe == search:
             #write the modified record to the temp file.
             temp_file.write(recipe + "\n")
             temp_file.write(ingredient1+ "\n")
             temp_file.write((quantity1*input(new_number_of_people)) + "\n")
             temp_file.write(units1 + "\n")
             temp_file.write(ingredient2+ "\n")
             temp_file.write((quantity2*input(new_number_of_people)) + "\n")
             temp_file.write(units2 + "\n")
             temp_file.write(ingredient3+ "\n")
             temp_file.write((quantity3*input(new_number_of_people)) + "\n")
             temp_file.write(units3 + "\n")
             temp_file.write((new_number_of_people) + "\n")

             #Set the found flag to True.
             found = True
        else:
                 #write the original record to the temp file.
                 #write the modified record to the temp file.
             temp_file.write(recipe + "\n")
             temp_file.write(ingredient1+ "\n")
             temp_file.write((quantity1*input(new_number_of_people)) + "\n")
             temp_file.write(units1 + "\n")
             temp_file.write(ingredient2+ "\n")
             temp_file.write((quantity2*input(new_number_of_people)) + "\n")
             temp_file.write(units2 + "\n")
             temp_file.write(ingredient3+ "\n")
             temp_file.write((quantity3*input(new_number_of_people)) + "\n")
             temp_file.write(units3 + "\n")
             temp_file.write((new_number_of_people) + "\n")


         #Read the next recipe
        ingredient1 = str(recipeList_file.readline())
        quantity1 = float(recipeList_file.readline())
        units1 = str (recipeList_file.readline())
        ingredient2 = str(recipeList_file.readline())
        quantity2 = float(recipeList_file.readline())
        units2 = str (recipeList_file.readline())
        ingredient3 = str(recipeList_file.readline())
        quantity3 = float(recipeList_file.readline())
        units3 = str (recipeList_file.readline())
        number_of_people = float(recipeList_file.readline())

        #Close the Recipe file and the temporary file.
    recipeList_file.close()
    temp_file.close()

        #Delete the original recipeList.txt file.
    os.remove ("recipeList.txt")

        #Rename the temporary file.
    os.rename("temp.txt", "recipeList.txt")

        #if the search was not found in the file display message
    if found:
        print ("The file has been updated.")

    else:
        print ("That recipe was not found in the file")
        #call the main function.
modify()
```

recipeList.txt format:

```
Cake 
Flour 
20 
grams 
Eggs 
2 
Number 
Butter 
2 
spoons 
1
```

Comment: Can you post the content of your "recipeList.txt"?  The format of the "recipeList.txt" is given or it's your choose? Using lists and .csv (see the csv module) file format you can save a lot of code.

Comment: This is the recipeList file content:-                                                   Cake
Flour
20
grams
Eggs
2
Number
Butter
2
spoons
1

Comment: Plz, see my edit of your question. One data per row, is it correct?

Comment: Yes it is. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The format of the input file isn't the best.  I shall be better each recipe in a row and each data with a separator (comma), a csv format.

But as the input is given in that format...

First, is a good habit to make a function for each task.  Thus I think in 3 tasks:

1. Input from user: question()
2. Read the data and process it: modify()
3. Save the processed data into a file: save()

**`question()` function.  Explanation:**

Ask to the user for the input data and I return in a tuple.

**`modify()` function.  Explanation:**

After opened the file input I read() all the file, and split each line using the '\n' separator.  This makes a list with the content of each line of the file.

As the name of the recipe is unique in the file and I want to access to a determinated recipe when I call the function, I think is better to use a dictionary where the name of 
the recipe is the key and the the other data (that I put it in a list) is the value.  Yes, 
the value of a dict can be any object in Python, thus I use a list.  I define a blank dict in order to add the recipes.

A recipe has 12 data (including the empty line at end), so with `zip(*[iter(recipeList)]*12)` I create a tuples of 12 elements that I can iterate with `for` statement.

The 0 index of the tuple is the name of the recipe that I use as key.  The rest of the tuple 
(using slices `[1:]` from the second element to the end) converted in a list is the value of the dictionary pair.  Why a list? Because tuples are inmutables in Python.

Then I iterate the list (from second element steping 3 elements; the quantities) updating the values with the product by number of eaters. And, at last I update the tenth item of the list with the number of people.

This function returns the update dictionary.

**`save()` function.** 
Try to code it yourself.  You only must to iterate the dictionary (with a list nested) and write to the new file of recipes each data in a line. (Don't forget write the key of each dictionary pairs, is the name of the recipe).

```
import os

def modify(recipe_name, number):
    recipeList_file = open('recipeList.txt', 'r', newline= None)
    recipeList = recipeList_file.read().split('\n')
    recipeDict = {}
    for i in zip(*[iter(recipeList)]*12):
        print(i)    # For debugging purpose
        recipeDict[i[0]] = list(i[1:])
        print(recipeDict.items())    # For debugging purpose
    for j in range(1, 10, 3):
        recipeDict[recipe_name][j] = str(int(recipeDict[recipe_name][j]) * number)
    recipeDict[recipe_name][9] = str(number)
    print(recipeDict.items())    # For debugging purpose
    recipeList_file.close()
    return recipeDict

def question():
    search = input("Enter a recipe name to search for: ")
    new_number_of_people = int(input("Enter the new number of people to serve (default is 1):"))
    return search, new_number_of_people


def save(dictionarySave):
    pass
    # Think yourself.

recipe_to_modify, number_to_modify = question()
new_recipe_dictionary = modify(recipe_to_modify, number_to_modify)
save(new_recipe_dictionary)
```